# FMDatabase query works with ? but fails with literal

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, fmdb

This is an odd problem. I've found a workaround that works, but I'd like to understand why, because I suspect it will come up again later in my code.  Here's the method that's giving my the problem:

```
FMDatabase *cardDatabase // initialized elsewhere
NSString *cleanChar; // this is the sanitized query string 
NSString *cardQueryString;
int cardID;

switch ([self studyLanguage])
{
    case CSStudyLanguageMandarinTraditional:
        cardQueryString = @"SELECT rowid, * FROM trad_char WHERE search = ";
        break;

// [...other cases...]

}

cardQueryString = [cardQueryString stringByAppendingString:cleanChar];

[cardDatabase open];
FMResultSet* cardSet = [cardDatabase executeQuery:cardQueryString];

BOOL foundCard = NO;

while ([cardSet next])
{ 
    foundCard = YES;
    cardID = [cardSet intForColumn:@"rowid"];
}

[cardDatabase close];
```

This code gives a database error:

```
DB Error 1: no such column: 意
```

where "意" is the character sequence I'm passing in cleanChar, which is apparently being treated as a column rather than a value somehow. However...if I add the search character in the query step, like so:

```
cardQueryString = @"SELECT rowid, * FROM trad_char WHERE search = ?";
FMResultSet* cardSet = [cardDatabase executeQuery:cardQueryString, cleanChar];
```

everything works just fine.

So I've actually solved the problem...but I want to know why, because it affects the way I'd like to do some more complicated queries with multiple joins down the road, where it'll be harder to just plug in variables at the end.

So: Is this a bug in FMDatabase? Do I just not understand how to use FMDatabase? Or is there some other problem with the code?

Answer (score 0):

Your query is failing because you haven't wrapped your search string in single quotes (used to designate literals). So you need to replace this line

```
cardQueryString = [cardQueryString stringByAppendingString:cleanChar];
```

with this:

```
cardQueryString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@'%@'", cardQueryString cleanChar];
```

However, that's bad practice, to compose the query by using NSString methods to combine the query string and query argument. It's problematic for several reasons, such as if the argument contains reserved characters or words, or escape sequences that open you up to SQL injection issues.

You should instead provide argument via the binding mechanisms of SQLite, which are wrapped up nicely in the FMDB methods. So, your "workaround" is actually the best method:

```
cardQueryString = @"SELECT rowid, * FROM trad_char WHERE search = ?";
FMResultSet* cardSet = [cardDatabase executeQuery:cardQueryString, cleanChar];
```

or send one or more arguments in an array:

```
cardQueryString = @"SELECT rowid, * FROM trad_char WHERE search = ?";
FMResultSet* cardSet = [cardDatabase executeQuery:cardQueryString arguments:@[cleanChar]];
```

Tom
BareFeetWare